# Is there a log4net pattern for machineName

Tags: log4net, pattern-layout

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on the various 'in the box' patterns like

```
%logger  
%level  
%timestamp
```

There is of course [the example page](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) but I'm not sure that's the full list of options.

I also know that it's possible to MDC parameters out of the app to the logger, but that involves a code change which is a different beast than a config change.

Is there a `%machineName` option, or `machineIP` option?  The issue is that we have all our servers in the web farm log into the same database log, and we're now thinking that a disproportionate number of messages are coming from one machine.

Answer (score 13):

```
%property{log4net:HostName}
```

Answer (score 12):

What I did just stumble across is

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="${COMPUTERNAME}"/>
```

and that seems to be working --- wonder what the difference is between this and the other options suggested. like `%property{log4net:HostName}`

Comment: ${...} depends on environment variables.

Comment: that works on all windows machines on which I tried. Very helpful!

Comment: I like it, why take a dependency on a custom class if you don't have to?

Comment: Your answer inspired me to get to this configuration that worked for me:
<file value="D:\somepath\${COMPUTERNAME}_BackEndLog.txt" />

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that gets the machine name:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using log4net.Layout.Pattern;

namespace YourNameSpace.Converters
{
    public class MachinePatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            writer.Write(Environment.MachineName);            
        }
    }
}
```

then set your log4net configuration like this:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <converter>
      <name value="machine" />
      <type value="YourNameSpace.MachinePatternConverter" />
    </converter>
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger %machine" />
</layout>
```

I like this approach as it can be reused and i can manage the information how i want. If you want to log the ip address for example, just do the same and create the converter like so:

```
public class IPPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return;

        writer.Write(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
    }
}
```

More info on the link: http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/creating-your-own-pattern-layout-converter-for-log4net/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [PatternString API](https://web.archive.org/web/20150831092452/http://logging.apache.org:80/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html), it looks like you would need to use %property in your pattern.  Also take a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627120503/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx), you may need to inject the machine name into the global context on application startup.

Comment: @AgileJon -- that article was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096452/1224858 about adding GlobalContext properties, I was able to get this to work.

I added the following code in my class file:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["hostname"] = Environment.MachineName;
```

And then in the config file I can reference hostname and it will appear

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{hostname}] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I think this is the "Compact Parameter Syntax" check out the last section over here http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html