# How do you include the thread number in a log4net appender even if the thread has a name?

Tags: log4net

In the ConversionPattern in a log4net config, is there a way to specify the thread number, even if it has a name?

e.g. something like the following: `[7] ThreadFoo`

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like it's supported.

Based on the the PatternLayout Class documentation listing all the output options [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html) the `%thread` variable seems to wrap the behaviour you want to change.

> You could possibly consider using Process ID instead? Depending on what your end objective is.

Have a look at this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096452/75963), it would look like:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["pid"] = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

and config usage

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%property{pid}" />
</layout>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you would need to use a `ThreadContext` and not `GlobalContext` because he's wanting thread level attributes.

Comment: I actually just need the thread ID to to be always printed, even if the thread in question has a name. This is because I'm dealing with a class that creates a set of threads, and gives them names. When you have multiple instances of that class, you end up having multiple threads with the same name in the log. I think I'll go with a custom/extended PatternLayout class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could add the thread id to the thread name:

```
Thread myThreadObj = new Thread(...);
myThreadObj.Name = "The thread name " + myThreadObj.ManagedThreadId;
```