# How to add processid to log4net layout?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm gonna use `log4net` in my `wpf` application. And I need messages in my log looks like this:

```
11/8/2018 10:49:38 AM   13 (5368)       properties disabled.
```

where `13` is `processId` which writes this message. So it's pretty easy. But unfortunately I can't achieve this. So I just need an appropriate pattern layout for my `log4net` logger.

I've found the [following message](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4net/tags/log4net-1.2.10/doc/release/faq.html#pattern-string) in faq section of `log4net` official site:

> The following example sets the file name for a `FileAppender` to include
>   the current process id by specifying the `%processid` pattern in the
>   File property.

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="log-file-[%processid].txt" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
</appender>
```

So and it works but only for file name not for layout in my log file. And I need to put this `%processid` into my layout. And my current layout is:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff tt} %processid (%thread) - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

And my log just writes `processid` string to my log file.

```
22/11/2018 16:21:51,863 PM processid (1) - Exiting application.
```

I've also **found** a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096452/364429). And it works. But `%processid` property is initialized only once during startup. And in my app *the writing proсes is often changes*. So this solution is not suitable for me. And I guess it could be achieved by default `log4net` layout settings.

The other option is using `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` as a type of my `conversionPattern`. But it is not suitable as well(if I use this type - `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` - in `conversionPattern` then `%threadId`, `%level` and even `%message` will be printed as string constants).

```
23/11/2018 16:22:52,456 PM 31560 [thread] level - message
```

But I need both `%threadId` and `%processid` in log.

Comment: @pfx actually it's not a duplicate.My original question had a link to that SO answer as well as explanation why it's not suitable for me. I have a bit different purpose.`%processid` has to be printed in my log file in each line. And it should be printed with the other parameter(`%threadId`, `%level` etc).So `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` is not suitable as well(if I use this type - `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` - in `conversionPattern` `%threadId`, `%level'`will be printed as string constants). So I need both `%threadId` and `%processid` in log(`%processid` DOES change in runtime)

Comment: @pfx nice, thank you

Comment: Can you make a small edit on your question? Without it, I can't remove the flag

Comment: @pfx I've just done some changes

Comment: Can you try using `ThreadContext`instead of `GlobalContext` `log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["pid"] = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;` which allows to have a different property value per thread.

Comment: @pfx I definitely should try this. But do I have to observe changing the value of `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` ? I guess I have to. And from other hand `log4net` already offers an approach how to work with `%processid`. So I assume there's a default solution for it. Moreover my log4net settings allow me to write `%processid` but not with the other param values( `%threadid`, `%meesage`

Comment: `%processid` is only defined for `PatternString`, not for a `PatternLayout`. Because of this, you need to use a `%property`, which is only a simple key-value pair.

Comment: @pfx yes, you're right. But I have to update this (`%processid`) property each time as well – isxaker 14 mins ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a custom [`PatternLayoutConverter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Layout_Pattern_PatternLayoutConverter.htm)   which outputs the process Id.
Doing so, you don't have to have to set and track the Id of the running process.

```
namespace PFX
{
    class ProcessIdPatternLayoutConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            Int32 processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            writer.Write(processId);
        }
    }
}
```

You then reference this `PatternLayoutConverter`in your `Log4net`config via its fully qualified assembly name as below.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">                        
    <converter>
        <name value="processid" />
        <type value="PFX.ProcessIdPatternLayoutConverter, PFX.Lib" />
    </converter>            
    <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff tt} %processid (%thread) - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```