# Why am I getting two log files per day using log4net with ASMX web service?

Tags: c#, iis, log4net, asmx, log4net-configuration

I have a ASMX web service running IIS 10 and have added log4net to the project with the following configuration:

```
<appender name="AsmxDebugLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="App_Data/ASMX.DEBUG_" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5GB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="AsmxDebugLogFile">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="AsmxDebugLogFile" />
</logger>
```

But for some reason, I'm getting two log files per day in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd.log.yyyy-MM-dd.log` as per the screenshot below, seemingly at random times as well, whereby the log file will switch to the newly created log file, and then will start logging again in the log file at was created at midnight of the day in question.  All log files are way below the 5GB max file size as well.

[image: Two log4net log files per day]

Below is an updated list of log files

[image]

It seems that initially, log4net logs to the file yyyy-MM-dd.log, and then after a random amount of time creates a new log file `yyyy-MM-dd.log.yyyy-MM-dd.log` starts writing to this log file and then goes back and logs to `yyyy-MM-dd.log` which was created at the start of the day.

These are the IIS recycle settings

[image: IIS Settings]

I am wanting 1 log file per day in the format of ASMX.DEBUG_yyyy-MM-dd.log.  Where am I going wrong with this configuration?

**UPDATE**

It seems that because we are recycling the application pool every 60 minutes depending on whether the log file is being written to at this time, depends on whether a new one is created.  Any suggestions as to how to overcome this issue.  At the minute I've now added the process_id in the log file name and it seems to work in that I get a new log file created every hour, but ideally I want just 1 log file a day.

Comment: Maybe look at file info (ownership?) of the two different file name formats to see if they are being created by the same user.

Comment: Also, should appender-ref be AppenderRef?

Comment: @GaTechThomas -- no, OP [has it correct](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: My guess would be that you are running this on IIS and that the App Pool is recycled after 20 minutes of inactivty. To disprove this you could check if the behaviour changes if you change the IIS Idle Time-out to 0.

Comment: Can you also show how do the files for the 28.4 and 29.4 currently look? If you can, watch what happens at 00:00 30.4.

Comment: @ZiggZagg Yes, it is a ASMX web service (using same Application Pool) which is recycled every 60 minutes.  I will add recycle settings to the question.

Comment: If the AppPool is restarted then the file names shouldn't change in such a way, and the created/modified times would not overlap.

Comment: Do two web apps run on the same machine with similar configs?

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, try temporarily disabling overlapped recycle and see if you still get two files.

Comment: @JohnWu I can't really change this setting as it will result in the service being unavailable whilst the application pool is recycled.

Comment: Do you have log config in web config or seprate file?

Comment: Can you also post your nuget package config? since i just tried your config locally and all works as expected :(

Comment: This honestly looks like a bug in Log4Net. I would change `staticLogFileName` to `true` and run it that way for a couple days and see what happens.

Comment: What Log4Net version is it?

Comment: you should not recycle application pool every hour. what happens to a process which is already running. This can cause issues when using in-memory sessions.Stay with default . Any way I did  not downvote your uestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **log4net** for all my applications and I never encountered this re-creation of file after a pool recycling.

Here are my parameter that differ from yours :

```
<appendToFile value="true"/>
<staticLogFileName value="true" />
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
```

And here's how the behaviour will be different :

- `staticLogFileName` means current day's file name will always be the same (`ASMX.DEBUG_.log` here). It will be automatically renamed with the date pattern on the day after.
- `appendToFile` means it will not overwrite current day's file, but rather append to it.

I think those first two parameters will avoid the creation of multiple file for the current day which may fix your problem.

- `MinimalLock`'s role is less clear to me, but I should mention it anyway :

> Opens the file once for each AcquireLock()/ReleaseLock() cycle, thus holding the lock for the minimal amount of time. This method of locking is considerably slower than FileAppender. ExclusiveLock but allows other processes to move/delete the log file whilst logging continues.

Answer (score 1):

```
<appender name="AsmxDebugLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
```

I think  you need Locking model which will not lock your file.I think when main file gets created and get locked. The File appender creates file name with same date time stamp over the exisiting file.
You should also use Remote path for logging like \\server\file\debug since you might have load balancer for IIS or Web server is hosted with static IP or F5.

Comment: Wow, I've been using log4net for years and never realized I could change the locking model. Regardless of whether this fixes the OP's problem, this is a useful answer!

Comment: I've updated my question, but the issue is to do with IIS application pool being recycled every 60 minutes.

Comment: Yes APP pool recycle can cause a new file. check this link for adding new process id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075603/log4net-process-id-information. adding processid will create same file pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try with this parameters.

```xml
  <param name="File" value="C:\YourLogFilePath\" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5GB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Comment: and why would this work for OP? Code-only answers help no one.

Comment: because of param file name and value, I haven't specified the file name to append I just define the path of the log file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "RollingFileAppender" which as its name suggests rolls to a new file on dates, try using the FileAppender, more information about how to use FileAppender you can refer to this link: [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

Comment: I am wanting 1 log file per day in the format of ASMX.DEBUG_yyyy-MM-dd.log, using `FileAppender` creates just 1 log file in its entirety.